# Flink unable to connect with kafka and hadoop in cluster setup using docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

**Setup Details:**

We have Flink which performing real time data analysis with the help of Apache Kafka and for fault tolerance we have hadoop which will take care checkpoint and savepoint.

Kafka-Flink-Hadoop all are clustered.

We are using docker swarm to run all the setup.

Docker swarm yml file for flink cluster:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.7-hadoop28-alpine
    hostname: jobmanager
    ports:
      - target: 8081
        published: 8081
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.ip == host1]
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
    command: jobmanager
    volumes:
      - /etc/flink-cep:/etc/flink-cep
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager

  taskmanager1:
    image: flink:1.7-hadoop28-alpine
    hostname: taskmanager1
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.ip == host1]
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
    command: taskmanager
    volumes:
      - /etc/flink-cep:/etc/flink-cep
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager

  taskmanager2:
    image: flink:1.7-hadoop28-alpine
    hostname: taskmanager2
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.ip == host2]
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
    command: taskmanager
    volumes:
      - /etc/flink-cep:/etc/flink-cep
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager

  taskmanager3:
    image: flink:1.7-hadoop28-alpine
    hostname: taskmanager3
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.ip == host3]
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
    command: taskmanager
    volumes:
      - /etc/flink-cep:/etc/flink-cep
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
```

**Problem statement:**

Frequent timeout is happening after that flink job is getting crashed.

Is there anything to modify above yml file to handle timout scenario?

Is there any workaround ?

Please do not mark it as duplicate, because i have not got the proper answer.

**Reference:**

We found this open issue in docker official page.

https://success.docker.com/article/ipvs-connection-timeout-issue